# PHP scope of $this in included file in class method

Tags: php, class, methods, instance

I have a method in one of my classes which looks like,

```
public function render() {

    foreach ($this->_levels as $level) {

        ob_start();

        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $level[0] . '/' . $level[1] . '.php';

        if (file_exists($path)) {

            require($path);
        }

        $content = ob_get_clean();

        if ($content) {

            $this->_content = $content;
        }
    }

    return $this->_content;
}
```

In the included file I have access to `$this`. Is there anyway in which I can cause this not to happen? (So `$this` is not defined?)

I have tried wrapping it in an anonymous function and binding to null but it does not work.

Comment: You want to remove the usage of $this->_levels and $this->_content ?

Comment: No, the file which is included is in the scope of $this, I want to remove the object scope from the included file, (as if it were included from outside of the class method)

Comment: Then just don't include that file. There are other ways to inject data/code/whatever. Therefore: XY problem. What are you trying to achieve (i.e. what did you try to solve when you came up with the idea to include a file within a class method definition?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new function outside of your class and `require` your file from there. Composer is doing that in their [ClassLoader.php](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L405-L413).